# HTML5 validation not catching '...'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, html

I have a regular expression for validating format of a name. You can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/fSpwE1/2). 
This regex does not match `...`. But in browser it is somehow allowed by client-side validation, and is only caught by my server-side validation.

#### View

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper

    def name_field(name, options = {})
      validation_options = {
        pattern: "^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ ',.-]+$",
        oninvalid: "setCustomValidity('Contains unsupported characters.')",
        oninput: "setCustomValidity('')"
      }
      text_field name, validation_options.merge(options)
    end
  end


<%= f.name_field :last_name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name', required: true, maxlength: 50 %>
```

#### Model Validation

```
  NAME_FORMAT = /^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ ',.-]+$/

  def name_is_acceptable
    [:first_name, :last_name].each do |attr|
      value = self.send(attr)
      next if value.blank? || value =~ NAME_FORMAT

      errors.add attr, I18n.t(:resident_name_invalid, scope: 'errors.messages')
    end
  end
```

Comment: That "client side" code does not appear to be JavaScript; what tag should the question have?

Comment: @Pointy The client side is a rails helper. I will post an example of it being used.

Comment: Well "client side" means "code that runs in the web browser".

Comment: @Pointy This is code being run on the browser. It is template code, ERB, which generates html.  `<input pattern="^(?!.*.S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ ',.-]+$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Contains unsupported characters.')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required="required" maxlength="50" size="50" type="text" name="resident[first_name]" id="resident_first_name">`

Comment: It looks as if backslashes were removed. Try doubling them, or use something like `(?!.*[.][^ ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is in double-quotes, so `\` escapes are handled by ruby (and ignored, since characters after that are not special), while these should go to regex in browser.

Use:

```
pattern: '^(?!.*\.\S)[a-zA-Z àâäôéèëêïîçùûüÿæœÀÂÄÔÉÈËÊÏÎŸÇÙÛÜÆŒößÖẞąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻìíòúÌÍÒÚáñÁÑ \',.-]+$'
```